# Related columns in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have two columns (selection column), the first is Country and the other is City. My question is:¿How can I show the cities of a specific country?

Comment: Have you looked into Lookup Columns? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx

Comment: An answer to a similar question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/cascading-dropdown/94601#94601

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a Term Set and Managed Metadata column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use InfoPath, you can make cascading dropdown list boxes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharatgupta/archive/2013/03/07/create-cascading-dropdown-in-browser-enabled-infopath-form-using-infopath-2010.aspx